# Which files need to be deployed on IIS when you republish code?

Tags: asp.net, iis, publish

I have an ASP.NET application with published code running in IIS. Now I've made some changes to the application pages and republished the code.

Which files/folders do I now need to redeploy on IIS?

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if you've made changes in C# class library, then you will need to update just DLLs. And if you've changed `aspx` or `aspx.cs` file the you will need to update that published page.